# How do I save search terms in the redux state?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm learning redux by using it with a react app that pulls articles from the Hacker News API.

I want to save the search terms inputted in the search bar to the redux state, but when I look at the state, the searchTerm state I have made is empty in redux devtools.

Here is my search bar component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import getSearchTerm from '../actions/searchAction';

class Search extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        searchTerm: ''
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const searchTerm = this.state.searchTerm

    this.props.getSearchTerm(searchTerm);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="searchTerm"
                    style={{
                        width: "95%",
                        paddingTop: 8,
                        paddingBottom: 8,
                        paddingLeft: 16,
                        fontSize: 24
                    }}
                    placeholder="Enter term here" onChange={this.onChange}
                    value={this.state.searchTerm} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
}


Search.propTypes = {
    searchTerm: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const mapPropsToState = state => ({
    getSearchTerm: state.searchTerm
})

export default connect(mapPropsToState, { getSearchTerm })(Search)
```

Here is the action I am using to save the search term:

```
export const getSearchTerm = term => dispatch => {
console.log('action called')
dispatch({
    type: GET_TERM,
    term
})
}
```

And here is the reducer:

```
import GET_TERM from '../actions/types';

const initState = {
    searchTerm: null
}

export default function (state = initState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TERM:
            return {
                searchTerm: action.term
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I am also getting a warning in my console saying:

> 'Failed prop type: The prop `searchTerm` is marked as required in
>   `Search`, but its value is `undefined`.'

Obviously, this means the search term I have required is undefined because I have it as undefined in the reducer. However, I want to save the search term I enter into the redux state. How do I go about this?

Comment: Umm, you don't. Redux should only be used for global states. Search inputs and saving their content should be managed in the component's local state. If you wanted this to persist, then maybe you should use localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Can your check if your reducer is getting it. Just console.log() it before returning new state in your reducer.

Also use should always spread the state in every return in order to ensure that your overall state doesn't get overwritten.

Posted as I don't have comment privileges.

Comment: console logged this.props.getSearchTerm(this.state.searchTerm) and it comes up as undefined, even after I put in a search term. And I thought you only had to spread the state if it was an object or array. Can singular elements like strings be spread as well?

Comment: state is an object containing a key with string value, so yes it can be spread.

Comment: `import GET_TERM from '../actions/types';

const initState = {
    searchTerm: null
}

export default function (state = initState, action = {}) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_TERM:{ console.log(action.term);
            return {
                searchTerm: action.term
            }}
        default:
            return state
    }
}`

Comment: Use this as your reducer and see if action.term has the correct value or not in console.

Comment: Nope, still coming up as undefined in the console.

Comment: Try replacing console.log("action called") with console.log(term) in your getSearchTerm function. That way we will know if is it being passed correctly.

Comment: If it still says undefined can you log searchTerm in onSubmit function?

Comment: I can log the input when I call this.state.searchTerm which tracks the state locally in the component, but not in redux. this.props.searchTerm or this.props.term come back undefined.

Comment: `const mapPropsToState = state => ({
    getSearchTerm: state.searchTerm
})`  Can you change the getSearchTerm to just searchTerm?

Comment: The problem is both your function and state have the same name                                `const mapPropsToState = state => ({
    *********getSearchTerm**********: state.searchTerm
})

export default connect(mapPropsToState, { ****getSearchTerm***** })(Search)`

Comment: `export const getSearchTerm = term => dispatch => {
console.log(term)
dispatch({
    type: GET_TERM,
    term
})
}` Does this also log undefined?

Comment: Yes it does, so does that mean the action isn't being executed in the first place?

Comment: Most likely. Can you log something in reducer to ensure action is getting dispatched?

Comment: I have console.log(action.term) in my GET_TERM case already. I immediately get undefined when the page is reloaded so does that it's logging the action or the reducer there?

Comment: It shouldn't happen on page reload, it should happen on button click

Comment: I think it's because the api takes an empty query as "undefined" and since there are HN articles with undefined in the titles, it shows those results.